# Pokemon stat calc

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green, pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

I'm looking for a gen1 & gen2 explanation of how stats are calculated based on a pokemon's level and other inputs.

[This](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/696959-pokemon-x/68539129) is a good breakdown of gen3+ according to the writer, but nothing on earlier generations.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

[This section](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Statistic#In_Generations_I_and_II) on Bulbapedia pretty much sums up what you want to know if I understand what you're looking for correctly. The main difference between the formula in generation 1 and 2 and the formula from generation 3 onwards is the use of the Pokemon's nature in statistic calculation.